# Positioning text under a image that is being autosized

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having some CSS issues. I am resizing images based on the size of the users browser window but when I do this my text goes through the image. I can solve this by giving the container a height in pixels rather than auto but that doesn't look right when resizing the browser.

I have made a simple example of my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/34k2H/1/

```
<div id="coverContainer" style="position:relative; height:auto; width:100%;" class="center-block">
    <img class="photo center-block" src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />

</div>


<div class="center-block">
    <h2 style=" color:black;">
        Welcome to my website
    </h2>
    <div id="news">
        <h2 style="color:black;">News</h2>
        <p style="color:black;">Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text Example Text .</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.photo {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    position:absolute;
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

I would like the text to always be under the image.

Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image has a `position: absolute`, I fixed it for you in the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/34k2H/2/